# Several papers appear to imply P=NP via chordal graphs, what is wrong?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Several papers appear to imply P=NP via chordal graphs, 
which suggests something is wrong.

As usual $\gamma(G)$ is the domination number and $i(G)$ and $\gamma^i(G)$
are the independence domination number.

According to [VIZING’S CONJECTURE FOR CHORDAL GRAPHS, p.1](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/szabo/PS/vizing.ps)

> Theorem 1.1. [2] In chordal graphs $\gamma(G)=\gamma^i(G)=i(G)$.

According to [graphclasses.org](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_32.html)

and a [paper p. 55 of the document and 65 of the pdf](http://thomas-szymczak.de/dissertation.pdf):

> In chordal graphs Domination is NP-complete and Independent Domination is
>   polynomial.

The equality in Theorem 1.1 appears to imply P=NP since we can compute
$\gamma(G)=i(G)$ in chordal graphs by the above result.

> What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you confused the definiton in the paper of Aharoni & Szabo and the normally used definition for the term "independence domination number". The former one refers to the largest size over all minimum set **dominating an independent set**, and the latter one is the smallest size of **a dominating set which is also an independent set**.

These two definitions are quite different, and as you noticed they have different symbols: $\gamma^i(G)$ and $i(G)$. The Theorem 1.1 you mentioned actually claims $\gamma(G)=\gamma^i(G)$ for chordal graphs $G$, and generally they are not equal to $i(G)$ even when $G$ is chordal. The following graph is a counterexample:

[image: example]

where $\gamma(G)=2$ and $i(G)=3$.

As a comment, Allan & Laskar showed that $\gamma(G)=i(G)$ when $G$ is [claw-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph), but there are no such conclusions for chordal graphs.

Comment: Thanks, indeed there are counterexamples to gamma(G)=i(G) for chordal.

Comment: So, just to be clear, we're saying that `Theorem 1.1` in OP's question is wrong, right? @WillardZahn

Comment: @MillieSmith The paper in the link only claims $\gamma(G)=\gamma^i(G)$, and the one in question is indeed wrong.